# getUserMedia constraints does not correspond to capabilities

Tags: javascript, mediastream

I have a webcam with sensor resolution 1280x720 (HP Webcam 2300). When running the code:

```
    var video = document.createElement('video')
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: {width:1280}})
    .then(stream=>{
        const track = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
        console.log(
            track.getCapabilities(),
            track.getSettings(),
            track.getConstraints()); 
    });
```

From `getCapabilities` I get width `{max: 1280, min: 1}`, which agrees with hardware specified webcam capabilities.

`getConstraints` has width set to `1280` as ideal width, as expected.

But from `getSettings` I get a width value of `320`, and attempting to exceed this value by setting a minimum width causes an `OverconstrainedError`.

What is the cause of this discrepancy?

Observed on Google chrome 72.0.

Comment: Did you find out the cause?

Comment: Yes, it's a [bug in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=943469&can=1&q=From%20getCapabilities%20mikael&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) when multiple tracks are used simultaneously with different constraints. See comment 11 in the link for an explanation and possible workaround for that particular case. Otherwise, check if any other tabs use camera